# Git post-receive not working but post-commit does

Tags: git

Long story short, I created a test repo on github, cloned it locally on my linux machine. Created a post-commit hook with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Test message
```

Added perms 777 for the hook, changed a file and when I performed the commit, I got the message on the console. So the post-commit hook seems to work. I now renamed the hook from post-commit to post-receive but after push I get no message. I keep committing and pushing to master and no message is displayed. The hook is just the same, has 777, has same content so I can't understand why as post-commit the hook works but as post-receive it doesn't. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the fact that hooks run on the local repo, and do not transfer between repos.  So, the `post-receive` hook you've got in your repo only runs when *your* repo receives something, not when the remote repo receives something.

In the case of Github, specifically, you can't setup "traditional" hooks, because Github doesn't want to be stuck running arbitrary code on their servers (crazy, huh?)  So, instead, they provide "[web hooks](https://help.github.com/articles/about-webhooks/)" which trigger a HTTP request to a URL you specify whenever a git hook would otherwise have run.